# Multiple LIKE matches with Arel & MetaWhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, searchlogic, arel, meta-where

I'm transitioning an application written in Rails-2.3 with [SearchLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) to Rails-3.0 with Arel and [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/), and I'm running into an operation that I don't know how the write.

The old code was:

```
if params[:city] && params[:city].respond_to?(:each)
  users = users.person_address_city_like_any(params[:city])
end
```

what this did was run a `LIKE` match against each item in the params[:city] array.

This is easy enough in MetaWhere when there's only one search term:

```
users = users.where(:person => { :address => { :city.matches => '%city1%' } })
```

but how would I write this with an arbitrary number of cities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

users = users.where(:person => { :address => { :city.matches_any => ['%city1%','%city2%'] } })

Comment: Thanks. I'm very impressed with MetaWhere so far.

Comment: how can I do that very same thing when the conditions come from a string: "person.address.city"?